# How to send salesforce object field data to Docusign Template

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, apex

I have requirement where I need to send email template from the docusign and docusign template should have the salesforce object field data (specific fields) and I am using docusign APIs (custom API) not an application in this case, how I will be able to achieve this.

I have gone through it's documentation and also gone through many articles where it is recommending to use docusign application (managed package) for sending data from salesforce to docusign but in my case whatever code I will be adding it will be in managed package that is why I have to strictly use APIs only.

**Note** I have already written the integration where I am able to sending the templates from the docusign but my finding is how I can send salesforce data to docusign, or is there way to create dynamic template which will use salesforce object data.

Answer (score 0):

To send SalesForce data to DocuSign, you have to use the DocuSign Apps Launcher for Salesforce which is a package of apps that work together to generate and send contracts for review, approval and signature.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/

Most DocuSign workflows and processes can be accomplished through the DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce UI, they can be customized and automated more extensively using the DocuSign API functionality exposed by the Apex Toolkit. If your Salesforce implementation uses Apex to customize DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce, we recommend installing and using the Apex Toolkit.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/salesforce/salesforce101/apex-toolkit/

Comment: thanks for the response, I am basically using the Rest API in my package for DocuSign and if I install Apex-toolkit in my org, it will create dependency whenever I will installed my package in another org.